# SparkSQL : Problem in doing the Unpivot for a table

Tags: sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, amazon-redshift, aws-glue

I have input redshift table like this which I am trying to do transformation using spark.sql thru AWS glue job

```
name   quality DAV  BAV  LAV  KAV
Deli    Good   YES  NO   YES  YES
Beli     ok     NO  YES  NO   YES
```

Expected output after doing unpivot

```
name  quality Priv_Name Priv_Value
Deli    Good  DAV       YES
Deli    Good  BAV       NO
Deli    Good  LAV       YES
Deli    Good  KAV       YES
Beli     ok   DAV       NO
Beli     ok   BAV       YES
Beli     ok   LAV       NO
Beli     ok   KAV       YES
```

I am trying this

```
df_Priv_File = spark.sql(f"""SELECT *
    FROM input_file UNPIVOT (Priv_Value FOR Priv_Name IN (DAV,
        BAV, LAV,KAV))
        """)
```

But getting below error

```
mismatched input 'FOR' expecting {')', ',', '-'}(line 2, pos 47)

pyspark.sql.utils.ParseException: mismatched input 'FOR' expecting {')', ',', '-'}(line 2, pos 47) == SQL == SELECT * FROM input_file UNPIVOT (Priv_Value FOR Priv_Name IN (DAV, -----------------------------------------------^^^ BAV, LAV,KAV))
```

What I am missing?